# Phrasing Json response in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, response

So I have come to a slight issue in phrasing this api response.
I'm trying to phrase the screenshot data from this api response?..

I have tried the below but to no avail!.. It just seems to be NULL?..
any help would be great thanks

```
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);
$testt = $jsonData->screenshot->data;
```

**The response:**

```
    {
 "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "http://stackoverflow.com/",
 "responseCode": 200,
 "title": "Stack Overflow",
 "score": 78,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 31,
  "numberHosts": 11,
  "totalRequestBytes": "4412",
  "numberStaticResources": 22,
 },
 "formattedResults": {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "ruleResults": {
   "AvoidLandingPageRedirects": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Avoid landing page redirects",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page has no redirects. Learn more about avoiding landing page redirects.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/AvoidRedirects"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "EnableGzipCompression": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Enable compression",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "You have compression enabled. Learn more about enabling compression.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "LeverageBrowserCaching": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Leverage browser caching",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "You have enabled browser caching. Learn more about browser caching recommendations.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MainResourceServerResponseTime": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Reduce server response time",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your server responded quickly. Learn more about server response time optimization.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyCss": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Minify CSS",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your CSS is minified. Learn more about minifying CSS.",
       "args": [
        {
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyHTML": {
    "ruleImpact": 0.1443,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Compacting HTML code, including any inline JavaScript and CSS contained in it, can save many bytes of data and speed up download and parse times."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Minify HTML for the following resources to reduce their size by $2 ($3 reduction).",
       "args": [
        {
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        },
        {
         "value": "1.4KiB"
        },
        {
         "value": "5%"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Minifying $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction) after compression.",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "1.4KiB"
          },
          {
           "value": "5%"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyJavaScript": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Minify JavaScript",
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your JavaScript content is minified. Learn more about minifying JavaScript.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinimizeRenderBlockingResources": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content",
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "INT_LITERAL",
         "value": "2"
        },
        {
         "type": "INT_LITERAL",
         "value": "3"
        }
       ]
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=174f553de1d0"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=55bbe6171ff2"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/company.min.css?v=86ee8c8bfa3e"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/sidebar.min.css?v=88f3fd5e2263"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "OptimizeImages": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Optimize images",
    "ruleImpact": 3.0802000000000005,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Optimize the following images to reduce their size by $2 ($3 reduction).",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages"
        },
        {
         "type": "BYTES",
         "value": "30KiB"
        },
        {
         "type": "PERCENTAGE",
         "value": "42%"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/careers4-ad-header-so-crop.png?v=f4ca4345dc81"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "16.6KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "73%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "2.9KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "19%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/sprite-herobox.png?v=d173774f3a9f"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "2.8KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "43%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfe0K.png"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "2.6KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "76%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/vobok.png"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "2.6KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "76%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "1.5KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "9%"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Losslessly compressing $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction).",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1dzB.png"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "962B"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "50%"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "PrioritizeVisibleContent": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Prioritize visible content",
    "ruleImpact": 2.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page requires additional network round trips to render the above-the-fold content. For best performance, reduce the amount of HTML needed to render above-the-fold content."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "The entire HTML response was not sufficient to render the above-the-fold content. This usually indicates that additional resources, loaded after HTML parsing, were required to render above-the-fold content. Prioritize visible content that is needed for rendering above-the-fold by including it directly in the HTML response.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Only about $1 of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response $2.",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "26%"
          },
          {
           "type": "SNAPSHOT_RECT",
           "value": "snapshot:5"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 "version": {
  "major": 1,
  "minor": 15
 },
 "screenshot": {
  "data": "***************8This is the data i need!!*********",
  "height": 240,
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "width": 320
 }
}
```

Comment: setting `true` in json_decode makes data associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `assoc` Parameter in `json_decode` on `true`, so it will return an array!
You just have to delete `true` like this:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($response);
$testt = $jsonData->screenshot->data;
```

Of course you can change `true` to `false` aswell:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($response, false);
$testt = $jsonData->screenshot->data;
```

More information about this in the **[PHP-Manual for json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)**

Answer (score 1):

use it like

```
$jsonData = json_decode($aa, true);
echo $jsonData['screenshot']['data'];
```

[***working code***](https://eval.in/169824)

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an error in your JSON on line 11 that stops json_deocde() returning a valid array (you should remove the trailing comma):

```
"numberStaticResources": 22,
```

Second, you are getting an array from json_decode() so you need to use the correct syntax:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);
$testt = $jsonData['screenshot']['data'];
```